# batch file - detect duplicate file names before char?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, duplicates

i have 70000 karaoke songs in folder "D:\Karaoke\". each one has two files

```
artist - songname [GT karaoke].mp3
artist - songname [GT karaoke].cdg
artist - songname [SJ karaoke].mp3
artist - songname [SJ karaoke].cdg
artist - songname [AF karaoke].mp3
artist - songname [AF karaoke].cdg
```

assuming all the files above represent the same song. I want to KEEP the AF version where it is and move all other files that match to a new folder called "D:\Karaoke\duplicates\". If no AF version exists then do nothing. would need to grab the file name before the [AF Karaoke] because its unique after that point.

Comment: What's with the `*.cdg'? Keep or move?

Comment: cdg is the lyrics portion that matches the timing of the mp3. cdg must stay with its corresponding mp3. if the mp3 moves the cdg must move too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would saddle the horse from the other side and begin searching for (`.mp3`) files whose names contain `[AF karaoke]` and if found then do something else do not ‐ like this, given that all the file names contain exactly one pair of brackets (`[` and `]`):

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Change to working directory:
pushd "D:\Karaoke" && (
    rem // Create sub-directory for dublicate items if not yet done:
    2> nul mkdir "duplicates"
    rem // Enumerate `.mp3` files whose names contain `[AF karaoke]`:
    for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=[] eol=]" %%A in ('dir /B /A:-D-H-S "*[AF karaoke].mp3"') do (
        rem // Enumerate all files whose partial names before `[` are the same:
        for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=[] eol=]" %%D in ('dir /B /A:-D-H-S "%%A[?? karaoke].*"') do (
            rem // Exclude files whose names contain `[AF karaoke]` and move the rest:
            if /I not "%%E"=="AF karaoke" ECHO move "%%D[%%E]%%F" "duplicates\"
        )
    )
    rem // Return to original directory:
    popd
)
```

This script does not really care about the file extensions (like `.mp3`, `.cdg`), neither does it regard the beginnings of the strings in between brackets other than `AF` (like `GT`, `SJ`).

After having tested for the correct output, **remove the upper-case `ECHO` command in front of the `move` command**!

Comment: thanks! this work! I changed this part ('dir /B /A:-D-H-S "%%A[?? karaoke].*"') to ('dir /B /A:-D-H-S "%%A[* karaoke].*"') since its not always two letters in the brand name. it worked in the few tests i did on some smaller batches. any issues you can see with that otherwise though?

Comment: also thanks for the comments in the code. easy to understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using command/line in same folder where these files are, try this:

---

```
For %F in (*)do echo/%~nF|find /v /i "[AF k" >nul && move "%~dpnxF" "D:\Karaoke\duplicates\" >nul
```

---

For bat file:

---

```
@echo off && cd /d "d:\folder\where\files\are"
For %%F in (*)do echo/%%~nF|find /v /i "[AF k" >nul && move "%%~dpnxF" "D:\Karaoke\duplicates\" >nul
```

---

- **Obs.:** If you want see move command results, just remove **`>nul`** in the end of line/command

  **<kbd>**[`For loop explained here`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**</kbd>**

Comment: the question is to move everything *except* `"*[AF k*].*`

Comment: Humm, my English, you know! Limited, thkX!